# Resetting counter-reset CSS values

Tags: css, list, inheritance, html-lists, counter

I'm struggling with counter-reset, the reset appears to be applying but then the following values seem to increment based on the value prior to the reset.

```
<head>
<style>
ol.list-number2{
   text-indent:10px;   
}
ol{
    list-style-type: decimal;
}
ol > li{
    display:inline;
}

/* Set the base count at 0 */
body{
   counter-reset:first 1 second 1;
}

/* Reset the count when the start class is available */
ol.list-start-number1:before{ counter-reset: first 0 second 0;}
ol.list-start-number2:before{ counter-reset: second 0; }

/* Prepend the ols with the counter and increment the counter */
.list-number1:before{
    content:counter(first) ". ";
    counter-increment: first 1;
}
.list-number2:before{
    content: "1." counter(second) ". ";
    counter-increment: second 1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="magicdomid25" class="ace-line">
        <ol class="list-start-number1 list-number1"><li><span class="a9z">test</span></li></ol>
    </div>
    <div id="magicdomid21231236" class="ace-line">
        <ol class="list-start-number2 list-number2"><li><span class="a9z">tesdfsdfsting</span>    </li></ol>
    </div>
    <div id="magicdomid31231230" class="ace-line">
        <ol class="list-number2"><li><span class="a9z">tessdfsdftyy</span></li></ol>
    </div>
    <div id="magicdomid26123" class="ace-line">
        <ol class="list-number2"><li><span class="a9z">tessdfsdfting</span></li></ol>
    </div>
    <div id="magicdomid30" class="ace-line">
        <ol class="list-number1"><li><span class="a9z">testyy should be two!</span></li></ol>
    </div>

    <!-- First list has ended -->

    <div id="magicdomid30" class="ace-line">
        <span>FEAR ME foo I am the resetter of counters</span>
    </div>

    <!-- Second list begins -->

    <div id="magicdomid25" class="ace-line">
        <ol class="list-start-number1 list-number1"><li><span class="a9z">I should be 1</span></li></ol>
    </div>
    <div id="magicdomid25" class="ace-line">
        <ol class="list-start-number2 list-number2"><li><span class="a9z">I should be 1.1</span></li></ol>
    </div>
    <div id="magicdomid25" class="ace-line">
        <ol class="list-number2"><li><span class="a9z"><b>I should be 1.2 but I'm not! :(</b></span></li></ol>
    </div>
    <div id="magicdomid25" class="ace-line">
        <ol class="list-number2"><li><span class="a9z"><b>I should be 1.3 but I'm not! :(</b></span></li></ol>
    </div>
    <div id="magicdomid25" class="ace-line">
         <ol class="list-number1"><li><span class="a9z"><b>I should be 2 but I'm not</b></span></li></ol>
    </div>
</body>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/E8XFK/85/

I assume I'm misunderstanding how counter inheritance works?

Modifying the DOM isn't an option here.

Answer (score 2):

The counters are inheritable, that means they follow css inheritance style - counters defined at top will be visible to the bottom. Also they're visible on the same document level, i.e. all sibling nodes will see previously defined counters as well. Counter-reset creates a new named counter. 
Since you have DIV > OL type structure, any counters defined on OL level will not be visible on the next row's DIV > OL.
What you're basically doing here is defining and using new counter on each row, thus they don't increment properly. The body style defines global counter which is used on rows where you don't "reset" counters, so you see incorrect numbering starting from the "second" items.

The correct solution is to create counters on a row level (DIVs with ace-line class) so they're visible inside the rows and on the next rows as well.

```
<div id="magicdomid25" class="ace-line list-start-number1">
    <ol class="list-number1"><li><span class="a9z">I should be 1</span></li></ol>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/E8XFK/92/